# Cent OS 7 MTA:SA Game Server Auto Start on boot

Tags: centos, boot, startup

Centos 7.2
Multi Theft Auto 1.5.3 Linux Server
This Game server runs fine.

I would like to know how to best auto start this game server for 24/7 operation on all occasions of server startup/reboot/crash? And I would like it start in a screen that starts detached/minimized but re-attachable.

I need an easy to understand step by step example.
the program to start is located here:
/home/gta3mta/multitheftauto_linux_x64-1.5.3/mta-server64